# What is the C++ standard library equivalent for mkstemp?

Tags: c++, libstdc++, mkstemp

I am transitioning a program that uses temporary files from POSIX `FILE` to C++ standard library iostreams. What's the correct alternative to mkstemp?

Comment: Not sure about `iostreams`, but there is always `tmpnam`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `tmpnam` is indeed a good alternative if you can ignore the (small) risk of a file with that name being created in between.

Comment: the STL is not the same thing as the C++ standard library. `STL` is commonly used to refer to the containers, iterators and algorithms components of the C++ standard library. IOStreams is not really part of the STL, and the STL doesn't need to have an equivalent for every part of the C standard library (which is also available in C++), or for various POSIX functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no portable C++ way to do it. You need to create a file (which is done automatically when opening a file for writing using an `ofstream`) and then `remove` it again when you're finished with the file (using the C library function remove). But you can use `tmpnam` to generate a name for the file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>

char filename[L_tmpnam];
std::tmpnam(filename);
std::fstream file(filename);
...
std::remove(filename);   //after closing, of course, either by destruction of file or by calling file.close()
```

Comment: This is unfortunate. Isn't there a way to open a stream from an already existing open fd?

Comment: @vy32 CatPlusPlus has a boost solution to do that, but if you don't want to use boost (like you said in your comment), then there won't be a portable way to create a stream from a file descriptor, I think.

Answer (score 6):

There is none. Note that `mkstemp` is not part of either C (C99, at least) or C++ standard — it's a POSIX addition. C++ has only `tmpfile` and `tmpnam` in the C library part.

[Boost.IOStreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html), however, provides a `file_descriptor` device class, which can be used to create a stream operating on what `mkstemp` returns.

If I recall correctly, it should look like this:

```
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int fd = mkstemp("foo");
if (fd == -1) throw something;

io::file_descriptor device(fd);
io::stream<io::file_descriptor> stream(device);

stream << 42;
```

Comment: Again, unfortunate. I don't want to use boost.

Comment: @vy32: That's silly. Boost is de facto a second standard library in C++. Avoiding it is counter-productive. AFAIK IOStreams doesn't have too many dependencies, so you can include it with your code if you don't want people to download it separately.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a portable C++ solution, you should use unique_path in [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem) :

> The unique_path function generates a path name suitable for creating
>   temporary files, including directories. The name is based on a model
>   that uses the percent sign character to specify replacement by a
>   random hexadecimal digit. [Note: The more bits of randomness in the
>   generated path name, the less likelihood of prior existence or being
>   guessed. Each replacement hexadecimal digit in the model adds four
>   bits of randomness. The default model thus provides 64 bits of
>   randomness. This is sufficient for most applications

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to use `boost`. It's not built in to my compiler, and I don't want to require people using my source code to download boost.

Comment: Boost's `unique_path` is as bad as `std::tmpnam` due to the race it leads to.

Comment: This doesn't change any of the issues `tmpnam` has: just tmpnam properly warns you of potential data races while this does not. You need to `open(O_EXCL)`, or you need another way to ensure there are no races.